# Can't prevent page reload after form submit/file upload

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, ajax, express

i want to upload photo with ajax to Express, but every time i submit a form it doesn't generate html that i have in code, it just redirects me and shows picture data as an object. is it even possible to upload a picture and if it succeeds, generate a desired response as html?

here's the Express code:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
   destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'public/uploads/basic_uploads/')
   },
   filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname)
   }
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

router.post('/ajax_upload', upload.single('ajaxFile'), (req, res) => {
   let data = req.file;
   res.status(200).json(data)
});
```

everything is ok with uploading a picture.

and then (Ajax):

```
$(document).ready(function (event){
      $("#uploadForm").on('submit',( function (event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax_upload",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: successHandler,
            error: function(error){
               $("#targetLayer").html(`<span>` + error + `</span>`)
            }
         });
      }));

      function successHandler(data) {
         // let html = `<img src="/uploads/basic_uploads/` + data.filename + `" >`
         // $("#targetLayer").html(html)
         $("#targetLayer").html(`<p>AT LAAAAAST</p>`)

      }
});
```

and here is html:

```
<div class="well">
                <form id="uploadForm" action="/ajax_upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="submitFormAjax();return false;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputFile">Ajax file Upload with Multer</label>
                        <input type="file" name="ajaxFile" id="exampleInputFile">
                    </div>
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Basic file Upload">
                </form>
                <div id="targetLayer"></div>

            </div>
```

Comment: i just want to show download link to a client

Answer (score 0):

after successHandler function add return false statement and try again,

```
$(document).ready(function (event){
  $("#uploadForm").on('submit',( function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax_upload",
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: successHandler,
        error: function(error){
           $("#targetLayer").html(`<span>` + error + `</span>`)
        }
     });
  }));

  function successHandler(data) {
     // let html = `<img src="/uploads/basic_uploads/` + data.filename + `" >`
     // $("#targetLayer").html(html)
     $("#targetLayer").html(`<p>AT LAAAAAST</p>`)

  }

 return false;
});
```

Comment: still redirecting me :(

Comment: try to replace button type from submit to button
 <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Basic file Upload">

Comment: i don't get an error, i just get redirected with json data on display, here is the screenshot: https://ibb.co/dSAZ7F
i have tried both solutions. return false, changing type="button".
i still get redirected.

Comment: i have solved the problem by removing submit input somewhere else and applying onclick method on it.